# A line segment in the closure of a convex subset of a topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem. Let $C$ be a convex subset of a topological vector space $X$. Let x be in the interior $C^\circ$ and let y be in the closure $\bar{C}$. I am asked to prove that in the line segment
\begin{equation}
 z(\lambda)= \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y
\end{equation}
points with $\lambda \in (0,1]$ all belong to the interior $C^\circ$.

If another point $x^{'}$ is in the interior, we have the open set $\lambda N_x + (1-\lambda) N_{x^{'}}$ to cover the points in between $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) x^{'}$ for $\lambda\in [0,1]$ ($N_x$ and $N_{x^{'}}$ are open neighborhoods of $x$ and $x^{'}$ in $C$). Therefore the preimage $z^{-1}(C^\circ)$ is an open and convex (connected) subset of $[0,1]$, which contains $1$ by definition. I want to rule out the possibility that for some $t>0$, $z([0,t))$ is contained in the closure $\bar{C}$ but not in $C$, presumably using the fact that $y\in \bar{C}$ and convexity of $C$. I don't know how to proceed though.

Comment: Maybe we should consider the linear homeomorphism $L_\epsilon (\zeta) = (1-\epsilon)\zeta + \epsilon y$, which maps $x$ to a point $x^{'}=(1-\epsilon)x + \epsilon y$ closer to $y$. For $\lambda\in(t,1]$, $\lambda x^{'} + (1-\lambda)y = \lambda(1-\epsilon)x+(1-\lambda(1-\epsilon)y) \in L_\epsilon(C)^\circ \subset C^\circ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my trial. I will try to explain my line of thought first. Preimages are a red herring here.

---

Let $O$ be an open neighborhood of zero such that $x+O  \subset C$.
We want to prove that $z+ \lambda O \subset C$.

Since $y \in \bar C$, for every open neighborhood $U$ of zero we can find
$x' \in ( y+ U) \cap C$ .
The problem is to find $U$ that works.
The idea is to ensure  that $\lambda (x+O)+ (1-\lambda)x'$ contains $z$.

We still have to find $U$. Since $x' \in ( y+ U) \cap C$, there is $u\in U$ with $x'=y+u$. Then
$$
\lambda (x+O)+ (1-\lambda)x' = z + \lambda O +(1-\lambda)u.
$$
So we need that $0\in \lambda O +(1-\lambda)u$, or equivalently $ u \in -\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}O$. The latter set is our $U$.

---

Lets start the proof.

Let $O$ be an open neighborhood of zero such that $x+O  \subset C$. Since $y\in \bar C$, there is $x'\in ( y-\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}O) \cap C$. Let $u:=x'-y \in -\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}O$.

Then
$$
\lambda (x+O)+ (1-\lambda)x' = z + \lambda O +(1-\lambda)u.
$$
Since $(1-\lambda)u \in -\lambda O$, it follows that $0 \in \lambda O +(1-\lambda)u$, so that $z\in \lambda (x+O)+ (1-\lambda)x'$.
Since $x'\in C$ and $x+O \subset C$, the open set $\lambda (x+O)+ (1-\lambda)x'$ is contained in $C$. And $z$ is an interior point of $C$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a simple proof. Let $L_t, t\in [0,1)$ be a linear homeomorphism
\begin{equation}
 L_t(\xi) = (1-t)\xi + t y
\end{equation}
Clear $L_0$ is the identity map and it maps $x$ closer to $y$ in the line segment as $t$ increases.

By convexity of $C$, $L_t(C)\subset C$. Let $O_x$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $C$, $L_t(O_x)$ is an open set contained in $C$, so is the union
\begin{equation}
 \cup_{t\in[0,1)} L_t(O_x)
\end{equation}
We have $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$ is contained in the open set above for $\lambda \in (0,1]$ (set $\xi=x,t=1-\lambda$), so they are all interior points of $C$.

Comment: You need to explain why $L_t(C) \subset C$ if $y$ is in $\bar C\setminus C$.

Comment: @daw Thank you for pointing it out. Indeed, not really a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is a $z$ in the relative interior of $[x,y]$ that is in the boundary of $C$. The boundary of $\overline{C}$ is the union of all the proper faces of $\overline{C}$.  In particular, $z\in F$ for some proper face $F$ of $\overline{C}$.  As the relative interior of $[x,y]$ meets $F$ and $F$ is a face of $\overline{C}$, we have that $[x,y]\subseteq F$. Since $F$ is disjoint from the interior of $\overline{C}$, which contains the interior of $C$, we conclude that $x$ is not in the interior of $C$. The resulting contradiction implies that all the points of $[x,y)$ are in the interior of $C$.